# Why Selecting text to beginning/end of line with Command + Shift + Left/Right Arrow not working in Google Chrome + Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I using latest version of Google Chrome and macOS Ventura (13.1). All of sudden keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd><-</kbd> or <kbd>-></kbd>) to select text to beginning/end of line stopped working with Google Chrome. It is working well with other app like Safari or VS Code.

Can any one tell what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It may case the issue was caused by the [Keyboard & Mouse for Xbox xCloud](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-mouse-for-xbox-x/nmfedkijhhigaikbadoijiolmjjgoimd) extension.

Answer (score 0):

Best suggestion I have is to check your chrome extensions. One of them might have that keystroke set as a parameter control. Switch each of them off individually and reload a page where you want to use your key combo to select text.

Answer (score 0):

That is an Apple defined key combination.

If you build an application using the Cocoa layer from Apple's SDK then this is automatically added. If you build your own GUI manipulation layer then you have to code it yourself. Cross platform apps ofent use a commonon GUI layer across different OS and do not call the Apple Cocoa layer and so can miss out common keystrokes. Chrome and Firefox both use their own GUI layers and don't set these shortcuts. But some apps e.g. VSCode do set it.

This is a Chrome bug so report it but don't expect a response as it will have been known since the first release.